# Combining Session Data with Database Data

Tags: php, mysql, session

I am new to this php topic, and the problem is that I do not know how to add data that is in the session and not inside the db.

I already tried several combinations to make the array path and add the total data but I have not been able to (can't multiply unit price), they are always presented individually and not the sum total (sum of total prices).

```
<div class="fresh-table">
    <?php
    /*
    * This is the console to get all the products in the database.
    */
    $products = $con->query("select * from product");
    if(isset($_SESSION["cart"]) && !empty($_SESSION["cart"])):
    ?>
    <table id="fresh-table" class="table table-responsive">
        <thead>
            <th data-field="cant" data-sortable="true">Quantity</th>
            <th data-field="prod" data-sortable="true">Product</th>
            <th data-field="total" data-sortable="true">Total</th>
            <th data-field="actions"></th>
        </thead>
        <?php 
        /*
        * From here we take the route of the products obtained and reflect them in a table.
        */
        foreach($_SESSION["cart"] as $c):
            $products = $con->query("select * from product where id=$c[product_id]");
            $r = $products->fetch_object();
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $c["q"];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $r->name;?></td>
            <td>$ <?php echo $c["q"]*$r->price; ?></td>
            <td style="width:auto;">
                <?php
                $found = false;
                foreach ($_SESSION["cart"] as $c) {
                    if($c["product_id"]==$r->id){
                        $found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                ?>
                <a rel="tooltip" title="Remove" class="table-action remove" href="cart/delfromfloat.php?id=<?php echo $c["product_id"];?> ">
                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
</div>
</br>
<span>
    <h3>
        <bold>Total: $
            <?php
            foreach($_SESSION["cart"] as $pr):
                $products = $con->query("select * from product where id=$pr[product_id]");
                $r = $products->fetch_object();
                $subtotal = $pr["q"]*$r->price;
                $sumArr[] = $subtotal;
                echo array_sum($sumArr);
            ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </bold>
    </h3>
</span>
</br></br>
<a href="carrito.php" class="btn btn-danger"><i title="Go to cart" class="fa fa-cart"></i> Go to cart</a>
<?php else:?>
<p class="alert alert-warning">The cart is empty.</p>
<?php endif;?>
</div>
```

Comment: Presumably this is quantity times price `$c["q"]*$r->price`, so you store that in an array like `echo $subtotal = $c["q"]*$r->price; $sumArr[] = $subtotal;` then where you want the grand total, you just `echo array_sum($sumArr);`...at least this is what I understand from your question. I don't know where the session part comes in other than checking that the cart exists and to loop through items.

Comment: Hello @Jhon117, Before using the `$_SESSION` make sure you have started the session at top i.e `session_start()`

Comment: tested, but the result on the screen: Total: $ 15000 30000 where 15000 is the first product, the second product is not shown, and shows the total sum of the two products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I commented, you need to store the subtotals and use `array_sum()` in the grand total:

```
<?php
function getCart($con)
    {
        if(empty($_SESSION["cart"]))
            return array();
        # Store the ids for the sql query
        # Store the qty values for later
        foreach($_SESSION["cart"] as $c) {
            $ids[]  =   $c['product_id'];
            $qty[$c['product_id']]  =   $c['q'];
        }
        # Default array
        $row    =   array();
        # Creating one query is more efficient then a whole bunch
        $sql    =   "select * from product where id IN (".implode(', ',$ids).")";
        $con->query($sql);
        # Fetch assoc so all values are arrays, not a mix of
        # arrays and objects (for consistency and ease)
        while($result = $con->fetch_assoc()) {
            # Create the quantity value from stored
            $result['qty']      =   $qty[$result['id']];
            # Create the subtotal value from stored and db
            $result['subtotal'] =   $result['price'] * $qty[$result['id']];
            # Assign the row
            $row[]              =   $result;
        }
        # Return cart array
        return $row;
    }
?>
<div class="fresh-table">
    <?php
    if(!empty($_SESSION["cart"])){
    ?>
    <table id="fresh-table" class="table table-responsive">
        <thead>
            <th data-field="cant" data-sortable="true">Quantity</th>
            <th data-field="prod" data-sortable="true">Product</th>
            <th data-field="total" data-sortable="true">Total</th>
            <th data-field="actions"></th>
        </thead>
        <?php 
        $grandtotal =   array();
        /*
        * From here we take the route of the products obtained and reflect them in a table.
        */
        foreach(getCart($con) as $item) {
            $grandtotal[]   =   $c["subtotal"];
        ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $item["qty"] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $item['name'] ?></td>
        <td>$ <?php echo $c["subtotal"] ?></td>
        <td style="width:auto;">
            <?php
            $found = false;
            foreach ($_SESSION["cart"] as $c) {
                if($c["product_id"]==$item['id']){
                    $found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            ?>
            <a rel="tooltip" title="Remove" class="table-action remove" href="cart/delfromfloat.php?id=<?php echo $item["product_id"] ?> ">
                <i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></i>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php   } ?>
</table>
</div>
</br>
<!-- Just echo the stored subtotals here, don't loop again -->
<span><h3><bold>Total: $<?php echo array_sum($grandtotal) ?></bold></h3></span>
</br></br>
    <a href="carrito.php" class="btn btn-danger"><i title="Go to cart" class="fa fa-cart"></i> Go to cart</a>

<?php
}
else { ?>
        <p class="alert alert-warning">The cart is empty.</p>
<?php 
} ?>

</div>
```